# Where to edit footer links Magento 1.9

Tags: footer, magento-1.9

I'm trying to figure out where to edit footer links in magento 1.9 but I couldn't find anything I'll be searching it for almost 3hours but no success. Sorry I'm just a newbie in magento.
I want to edit the links under "QUICK LINKS" "ACCOUNT" I found the link under company and it's in magento backend under static blocks but no success for the two.
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Bro, You can create your a custom static block and add it to your footer, just replace the old one. Hope that helps..cheers..

Comment: While correct this answer doesn't add to the value of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

These links are added in multiple layout files. The easiest way is to do a directory search (in your IDE) for "footer_links" phrase on the "layout/*.xml" files. You'll see that some links are being set in sales.xml, customer.xml or cms.xml. At the bottom of sales.xml for example you should see something like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer_links2">
        <block type="sales/guest_links" name="return_link"/>
        <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>return_link</blockName></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

This tells Magento to add the "Orders and Returns" link to the "Account" block in the footer. If you change the footer_links2 to footer_links, this link will end up in the "Quick Links" block. I think once you find this, you'll figure out the rest.

Answer (score 5):

The other links and title are set via layout system:

page.xml:

```
        <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="*" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
            </block>
            <!-- This static block can be created and populated in admin. The footer_links cms block can be used as a starting point. -->
            <!--<block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
            </block>-->
        </block>
```

Then in catalog.xml links are added:

```
<reference name="footer_links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="catalog" ifconfig="catalog/seo/site_map"><label>Site Map</label><url helper="catalog/map/getCategoryUrl" /><title>Site Map</title></action>
```

Comment: Hey, how do I add Account links in the static block? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The links are available on Admin menu -> CMC -> **static block**

Here available **Footer Links**, and repalace/modify the required links.

Answer (score -1):

on CMS/pages you can find an option to edit the footer whatever you want.

Comment: yep, you're right with that but the only content of the footer there is the links under "COMPANY".... any further suggestions?

Answer (score -6):

Hi it can also simple.

Paste in your style.css from your themes.

ul.links { display:none}

or on another class from the first block. And make new links in your first block in the admin by statisch block.

Comment: That should have been a comment, since it's not an answer.